# What type of soundness/knowledge soundness does Schnorr's proof of knowledge of a DLOG have?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, schnorr-identification

For clarification, the protocol works as follows: $P$ wants to convince $V$ that he knows $x$ such that $g^x=y$, where $g,y\in\mathbb{G}$ of order $p$; they perform the following steps:

1. $P$ samples $k\stackrel{R}\leftarrow\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ uniformly at random, computes commitment $r\leftarrow g^k$, and sends $r$ to $V$.
2. $V$ samples a challenge $e\stackrel{R}\leftarrow\mathcal{C}$ from a challenge set $\mathcal{C}$ (e.g. $\mathcal{C}=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$) and sends $e$ to $P$.
3. $P$ computes a response $s\leftarrow k+e\cdot x$ and sends $s$ to $V$.

$V$ then determines whether they accept the transcript $(r,e,s)$ by checking $r\stackrel?=g^s\cdot y^{-e}$.

I know the protocol is special sound, since from two transcripts $(r,e,s)$ and $(r,e',s'$) such that $e\ne e'$ we can extract $x$ via:
$$
x\leftarrow\frac{s-s'}{e-e'}
$$
I read Ivan Damgard's paper ([https://www.cs.au.dk/~ivan/Sigma.pdf](https://www.cs.au.dk/%7Eivan/Sigma.pdf) ), which I believe proves that Sigma protocols (with special soundness) have knowledge soundness with knowledge error $\kappa=|\mathcal{C}|^{-1}$. In other words, a cheating prover $P^*$ can only convince the verifier they know $x$ with probability $\kappa$ if they do not.

This is where my **first question** comes in: is the knowledge soundness statistical or computational? In theory, a computationally unbound cheating prover could produce an accepting transcript $(r,e,s$) with advantage $\epsilon$, they could solve the discrete logarithm problem with advantage $\epsilon-\frac{\epsilon^2}{p}$ (Theorem 19.1 in https://toc.cryptobook.us/book.pdf). So in that sense, does the knowledge soundness of the protocol rely on the hardness of the discrete logarithm problem. If so, is it therefore computational?

My **second question** is similar, but regards the regular soundness of the protocol. Since the protocol is special sound, we know that for a given commitment $r$, if there are two accepting transactions $(r,e,s)$ and $(r,e',s')$ where $e\ne e'$ then we can extract $x$. Therefore if we have an invalid statement (i.e. a statement with no witnes), the probability of proving the invalid statement is at most $|\mathcal{C}|^{-1}$, since there exists only one $e$ that could produce an accepting statement for every possible commitment $r$. Therefore, even a computationally unbound prover could not hope to break soundness with an advantage greater than $|\mathcal{C}|^{-1}$. So in that sense, is the soundness statistical?

Comment: To offer to other readers a bit more context on this question, I guess it derives from me not being convincing or correct here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/103339/how-to-calculate-soundness-error-of-a-sigma-protocol  
I hope to also improve my knowledge from this new question

Comment: Schnorr's interactive protocol is a *proof of knowledge*, that is the (knowledge) soundness guarantee holds against unbounded adversaries: see [Geoffroy's explanation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/56325/11441). Plain soundness is vacuous for the discrete logarithm relation since it is total, i.e., $\forall y\exists x:g^x=y$: explanation [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/79930/11441).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered the first part of the question [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/56317/schnorr-protocol-proof-or-argument/56325#56325): Schnorr is a statistical proof of knowledge, with knowledge error $1/p$ (or $1/|C|$ if you pick the challenge from $C$). That is, one can always extract the challenge, even against an unbounded prover, and no cryptographic assumption is required to prove the success of extraction.

As for the second question: for Schnorr, there is no notion of invalid statements. If $\mathbb{G}$ is a prime-order cyclic group with generator $g$, every element $h$ of $\mathbb{G}$ has a discrete logarithm in base $g$. In other words, the language is trivial: $\mathsf{L} = \{h \;:\; \exists x \in \mathbb{Z}_p, h = g^x\} = \mathbb{G}$. This is not an issue, precisely because the proof is a proof of knowledge: there is always a witness, but
*knowing* the witness is non-trivial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With regards to there being no notion of invalid statements, suppose a malicious prover $P^*$ chose $g=1$ and $y\ne 1$ from some prime-order cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Would this not be considered an invalid statement, or do we simply not "allow it" at all in the relation $\mathcal{R}$?

Comment: We simply don't allow it, since we insist that $g$ is a generator. Note that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is only a prime order cyclic group if you view it as an *additive* group, in which case $1$ is indeed a generator, and the relation becomes $\{y:\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}, y = x\cdot 1\}$, which is again trivial (but my previous point still stands if you consider instead a prime-order multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you very much.